# Can someone help me so that when I click on the button, The timer resets? Thanks

Tags: react-native

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, TextInput, Button,KeyboardAvoidingView, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';

const App=()=> {

    return (
      <View>
      <CountDown
        until={10}
        onFinish={() => alert('hello')}
        onPress={() => alert('hello')}
        size={20}
      />
      <Button title = "reset timer"
      
      
      >
      </Button>
      </View>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You could make the until prop a state variable and reset the variable to 10 when you click on your button.

Answer (score 0):

**set default value in state and when button press reset state**

**try this**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App=()=> {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(10);
    return (
      <View>
      <CountDown
        until={count}
        onFinish={() => alert('hello')}
        onPress={() => alert('hello')}
        size={20}
      />
      <Button title = "reset timer"
      onPress={() => setCount(10)}
      
      >
      </Button>
      </View>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Changing `id` seems to work, and according to their documentation, they specified that they are using `id` for resetting the timer.

But in React, we can use another workaround, we will give the `Countdown` component a `key` and change it randomly when and when the `key` is changed then the new `Countdown` component will be loaded and our timer will reset.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10)
  const [key, setKey] = useState("timer")
  return (
    <View>
      <CountDown
        key={key}
        until={10}
        onPress={() => alert('hello')}
        size={20}
      />
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('hi');
          setTime(10)
          setKey((Math.random()*1000000).toString())
        }}
        title="reset timer"></Button>
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;
```

You can might as well use `id` instead of `key` but I used `key` here.

You can paly with the code of the Working app here: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/crabby-macaroni-and-cheese)